# Uniform random variables generated by sums of independent Bernoulli random variables. Are they independent?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, independence

For $i\in \mathbb{N}$, let $\epsilon_i : \Omega \rightarrow \{0, 1\}$ be a Bernoulli random variable and suppose that this sequence is i.i.d. Let $\phi : \mathbb{N}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be a bijection, and define
\begin{align}
Y_i = \sum_j \epsilon_{\phi(i,j)} 2^{-j}. 
\end{align}
I want to show that the sequence $(Y_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ is independent.

> My attempt:
> For each $i$, the sequence of $\sigma$-algebras $\{\sigma(\epsilon_{\phi(i,j)}) : j \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is independent.
> Since $Y_i$ is $\sigma(\epsilon_{\phi(i,j)} : j \in \mathbb{N})$ measurable, it follows that the sequence $(Y_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ is necessarily independent.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct. Indeed, different $Y_i$'s depend on different $\epsilon_{\phi(i,j)}$'s, all of which are independent. Thus, the $Y_i$'s are independent as well.